# Is there a way to add user data to the nodes in SCIP?

Tags: scip

I am trying to add some user information to the nodes of the branch-and-cut tree in SCIP and when branching is performed on the node, I want the child nodes to inherit the same information as the parent. I can access the nodes via an event handler but I could not find a way to attach information to nodes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a hashmap in your event-handler and store the data that you want to save there.